# DialogFragment.show hangs app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which has a button. Once the button is clicked the following code executes:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View clickedView) {
        switch(clickedView.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnTest:
                FragmentManager fm = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
                dialog.show(fm, "TaskDeadlineDialog");
                break;
        }
    }
```

My Dialog Fragment is as follows:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment 
{
    public MyDialog() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedBundleInstance) {
        View currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, parent);
        System.out.println("Inflated!");
        return currentView;
    }

}
```

What happens is, the dialog doesn't show and the app stops responding. I am testing this on Samsung SII with CM9 ICS.

Edit: Logcat shows nothing either.

```
12-21 16:05:16.970: I/System.out(15753): debugger has settled (1304)
12-21 16:05:18.250: D/dalvikvm(15753): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
12-21 16:05:18.445: I/System.out(15753): Got ID: 1
12-21 16:05:20.430: I/System.out(15753): List position: 0
12-21 16:05:23.225: I/System.out(15753): Inflated!
12-21 16:05:38.510: D/dalvikvm(15753): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2265K, 41% free 4867K/8131K, paused 3ms+6ms
12-21 16:05:51.895: D/dalvikvm(15753): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1797K, 42% free 4787K/8131K, paused 2ms+2ms

..etc
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the log trace?

Comment: I've edited my post showing what logcat has to say about this :)

Comment: Hmm, maybe the `break` is causing the issue? I looked into dialogs with `switch-case` and found that instead of `break` people are returning the dialog, have you tried this yet? Example: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_working-with-dialogs/

Comment: @Daniel, i checked logcat from the terminal... does this have anything significant?
Input event dispatching timed out sending to com.app.myapp/com.app.myapp.myactivity

Comment: @Asok, it's a click event not an onCreateDialog event so returning the dialog instance won't work as the click event returns void :)

Comment: @Maverick You beat me to it, I noticed right before you replied and was about to delete my comments. :). You are correct, I am sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the following widget which i was inflating inside my dialog was causing the issue:
https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview

I'll make sure i report this to the developer on the project's issues page.

Answer (score 2):

All I can think of is that you might be blocking the ui thread for some reason. I guess this is quite a common mistake if you utilize synchronized operations or threading.

Take another look at your code and follow the procedure step by step. The Logcat should also be outputting timed out dispatches the longer you wait for the app to start responding again.

Edit; This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5047865/559157

Comment: hmm... i don't really seem to understand whats going on. This should be a normal UI operation. FragmentActivity shows fragment -> button clicked inside fragment -> fragment shows dialog fragment. I've checked the link you provided but there doesn't seem to be anything in common between my case and that one.